# Capturing filenames including parentheses with GNU Make's wildcard function

Tags: makefile, escaping, gnu-make

I'm going to render some plots from a set of data directories using Makefile to parallelize the process, but have problems with filename escaping with wildcard function.

This is the header of my Makefile:

```
SOURCE_DIR = ./results
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*cpuonly*) $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*cudaonly*)
$(warning $(SOURCES))  # for debugging
...
```

The example directory names are:

- blahblah-cpuonly-123
- blahblah-cudaonly-345
- blahblah-cpuonly-(123,567)

Here, the output of warning function includes only the directory names *without* parentheses.
How can I include those with parentheses as well?

**EDIT**: Of course, I could change the filenames NOT to include parentheses. But for this question, I'd just like to know whether using parentheses is impossible or not.

**EDIT2**: I tested it using filenames such as "blablah-cpuonly-(123,567).log" and the output includes them! However, it causes shell syntax error when executing the rules. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem (and I know of no restriction on parenthesis):

```
$ cat Makefile
foo := $(wildcard *foo*)
$(info foo = $(foo))
all: ;:

$ ls -1 *foo*
foo
foo-(bar,baz).bar
foo.mk

$ make
foo = foo foo-(bar,baz).bar foo.mk
:
```

Comment: It only happens with directories, not files. In your example, "foo-(bar,baz).bar" should be a directory to reproduce my problem. With files, there is another problem: shell syntax error when executing a rule using `$(SOURCES)` variable, but this is out-of-scope in the perspective of my question.

Comment: FYI, I'm using GNU make 3.81 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Ah, and I found that this problem only occurs when the name **ends with** ")". If there are any other characters after the closing parenthesis, the problem is not reproduced.

Comment: This looks like a bug in GNU make 3.81.  I can reproduce it with GNU make 3.81, but it works correctly with GNU make 3.82.